# Install Software's while provisioning azure vm using Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible

I am trying to Create a azure windows VM using ansible and while doing so i would like to install jfrog cli or run a powershell script which can do it.

I have a play book which can create a vm, create an vm extension and also create an image out of it. But i do not know how to install software's in that vm, before creating a image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on **azure windows VMs** at your work, you can package your applications which are in **.exe and .msi** format into ***chocolatey .nupkg format*** and host a **chocolatey nuget-hosted repo** in the **artifacts storage application like nexus**  where you can push and later source and install these **chocolatey .nupkg packages** that you want to install in these VMs using **win_chocolatey ansible module**.

**Sample task to install a chocolatey package:**

```
- name: "install packages from internal choco nexus repo"
  win_chocolatey:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    version: "{{ item.version }}"
  loop:
    - { name: 'jdk8', version: '8.0.xxx' }
    - { name: 'msbuildtools', version: 'xxx' }
```

**win_chocolatey ansible module:** https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_chocolatey_module.html

***What is chocolatey?***

```
Is is a framework to package applications which are in .exe or .msi formats into .nupkg
(nuget packages) which will have a installation script within the package and 
when you run choco commands to install a certain application, it either get
chocolatey packages from opensource chocolatey gallery or for organization 
purpose you might want to create custom package for network and security reasons.
```

**Chocolatey Documentation:** https://chocolatey.org/why-chocolatey

**How to create custom/offline chocolatey packages?**
https://chocolatey.org/docs/how-to-create-custom-package-templates

**Basic Chocolatey commands:**

`choco install <package-name> --version <version> -y` **--> by default gets choco packages from https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/**

`choco uninstall <package-name> -y` **--> to uninstall a package. --version option can also be used if a package of multiple versions have been installed**

`choco source add -n=<AnyName> -s="<URL-Internal-choco-repo>"` **--> adds internal chocolatey nuget-hosted nexus repos to chocolatey source on windows machines**

`choco source list` **--> Lists all added sources from where it gets packages**

`choco source remove -n="<NameOfSource>"` **--> To delete any source for list of all the chocolatey sources**

**Chocolatey commands:** https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/CommandsSources

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i will try this out, I have a Powershell script which can download artifacts from artifactory and install them. Do you know how can i use it with my current setup ? i.e vm gets created-> use ps script-> create image ?

Comment: @VinayUpadhyay are you trying to figure out ansible tasks to automate the flow you mentioned? i.e ```vm gets created-> use ps script-> create image```

Comment: yes i am trying to figure out a ansible task for the same

Comment: There are lot of resources to configure your ansible playbook to provision windows VM in your azure portal account. One that I found: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ansible-playbooks/blob/master/vm_create_windows.yml. You need to understand how ```winrm``` module works first to configure windows slaves from your local. Ref: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html.

Comment: Even before configuring windows VMs using ```winrm``` you need to run this script (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1) in the remote VM or server which you want to configure using ansible from your local. ```winrm``` uses 2 ports: For ```https: 5986``` and ```http: 5985```. So, you need to open these 2 ports in the remote server inorder to configure them using ```ansible winrm module```. Ref: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection/winrm.html